# What filters run on a single post but not archives or search results?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am looking to write a plugin that executes code on individual post pages but does not try to execute that code in search results or archives or anything that shows multiple posts in one place. I tried using a filter on "the_content", but that seems to execute everywhere. Seems this would be a simple thing to find out, but the dual meaning of the word "filter" has made searching for this pretty difficult.

As a related question, is there a good source for seeing what filters and actions are fired for different types of pages in a theme? I'm sure I'll have a similar problem in the future, and learning to fish will be helpful here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And maybe this code will be a good guide for you

```
function yourprefix_add_to_content( $content ) {    
    if( is_single() ) {
        $content .= 'Your new content here';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'yourprefix_add_to_content' );
```

Comment: Thank you. This is precisely the solution I was looking for. Wild that I couldn't find this through Professor Google, so thank you for the clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a condition where you specify that your code should only be executed on the single post or product

```
if(is_single('post_type')){
// add your code here
// Replace post type with the type of post you want this code to run on
}
```